# How do I use libcurl in Visual C++ 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, libcurl

Hey guys, I was wondering if you would be able to help me use libcurl within Visual Studio to resolve the errors in the image below:

[image: The error]

[image: The error]

Comment: Can you please provide what the Error List is when you try to compile your code ? That will make it easier to narrow down what is happening.

Comment: I'm going to summarize all the information below with the answer when Jerry response to my latest comment and give him credit. Thanks Jerry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to update Visual Studio's configuration to include the directories where you've installed cURL. VS has directories for both Include files and libraries -- if memory serves, you'll have to add both.

Comment: I've tried to do this in VSC++ and eclipse for hours... can't get the compiler to find the libraries. Pulling my hair out, should be relatively easy.

Comment: In VS 2008, it's: Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VC++ Directories, then select "Include Files", add the directory, and select "Library Files", and add that directory. I think it's about the same in 2010, but don't have access to it at the moment to check.

Comment: You have to go to properties on the project and select the directory... see error message above.

Comment: I've added the include directory to the include path, and the library directory to the library path in the project properties... no luck.

Comment: @Tyler: actually you *have* apparently had *some* luck: you're getting unresolved externals, which means it *is* finding the include directory and compiling the code. It's only linking to the library that's failing. I'd guess your directories are set up correctly (for both include and library files). Now you need to tell your project to actually link the cURL library (also make sure you've *built* the cURL library itself).

Comment: Very cool, if i downloaded it, would I still have to compile it? How do I tell VC++ to link to the library itself? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Tyler: Offhand I'm not sure with cURL (haven't used it in a couple years and don't remember) but having to compile the library is pretty common. Telling VC++ to link that library requires adding the library name to the "additional dependencies" in Linker -> Input of the project properties.

Comment: GOT IT! Now it's just saying it can't find curllib.dll... i'm pretty close, any ideas! You are helping a ton.

Comment: @Tyler: I'd just copy curllib.dll into the directory along with the executable. Assuming your creating a 32-bit executable, that'll be in either the `debug` or the `release` directory below where you created your project.

Comment: That totally worked, and it complained about more libs, so I added all the ones that came with the libcurl download, and then it finally complained about libsasl. Bummer. I have no idea where to get that and google yielded many people having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I too ran into same issue. The problem is, i was pointing in additinal lib dirs to lib/LIB-Debug instead lib/DLL-Debug. Also the lib to add is libcurld_imp.lib and not libcurld.lib. Also you need to copy libcurld.dll into executable file location. I see that there are lib/LIB-Debug dir and lib file but dont know what they are for. You have to do use DLL-Release, libcurl_imp.lib etc for release mode.